# codeigniter duplicate FOREACH

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm trying to take from mysql some data like a forum name comments number.

My code looks like that

```
<?php foreach(fetch('forum_threads', 'limit=5') as $forum_thread) : ?>
  <?php foreach(fetch('forums', 'limit=5') as $forum) : ?>
    <?php foreach(fetch('forum_sections', 'limit=5') as $forum_section) : ?>
      <li>
        <img src="/themes/<?php echo setting('themes.default_theme') ?>/assets/images/ico/neo-white.png">
        <a href="#comments" class="comments anim-01"><span class="anim-01"><?= $forum_thread->forum_posts_number ?></span></a>
        <h3><a href="./forums/<?= $forum->url_name ?>/<?= $forum_thread->id ?>/<?= $forum_thread->url_title ?>"><?= $forum_thread->title ?></a></h3>
        <span class="meta"><a href="./articles/<?= $article->section->url_name ?>"><?= $forum_section->name ?></a> - <abbr class="timeago" title="<?= $forum_thread->created_at ?>"><?= $forum_thread->created_at ?></abbr></span>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Everythings looks working, but i got 5 same forum threads like that:

```
    HELLO
    HELLO
    HELLO
    HELLO
    HELOO
    HELLO2
    HELLo2
    HELLO2
    HELLO2
    HELLO2
```

What i wanna to do looks like that:

```
HELLO
HELLO2.
```

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for answering! Cheers

Comment: Can't answer, you must give the piece of code where you are doing `echo $myforumthreadname` or something like that.

Comment: I'm tryed like that:   <?php 
foreach(array_slice(fetch('forum_threads'), 0, 5) as $forum_thread ):
foreach(array_slice(fetch('forums'), 0, 5) as $forum ):
foreach(array_slice(fetch('forum_sections'), 0, 5) as $forum_section):
  ?> but the same problem

Comment: The problem is not in your loop but after. But we need to see more of your code to answer...

Comment: thanks for answering. code after script: http://pastebin.com/bE6WjkGT

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
<?php foreach(fetch('forum_threads', 'limit=5') as $forum_thread) : ?>
```

Then print your forum thread name, then:

```
<?php foreach(fetch('forums', 'limit=5') as $forum) : ?>
```

Then print your forum URL, then:

```
<?php foreach(fetch('forum_sections', 'limit=5') as $forum_section) : ?>
```

Then print your forum section name. And finally close all foreach.